# Object are not in the correct orientation in the asset library. How do you change this?

Tags: edit-mode, asset-browser, asset

[image: All assets are rotated in the wrong direction]

Is there a way to edit the rotation of assets in the library so that when I drag them into the scene they will be in the correct orientation? I don't know why all of the objects are lying down.

Comment: You need to rotate them so the Z axis is up before marking them as assets

Answer (score 0):

Your orientation is set to local. Set it to global and everyhing will be ok.